# Dropbox access from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, bcs, office-365

I am new to Dropbox, and I'd like to know if there is an easy way to access Dropbox content from SharePoint 2010 / Office 365.

For example, should I consider BCS? Or is there a way to work with the Dropbox API?

Comment: I've thought about this many a time... I don't think there is an easy way with DropBox, however I think it may be possible using SugarSync and using a mapped drive to a SharePoint library...

Comment: @DavidLozzi thanks for the idea, but I am reluctant to duplicate the content.

Comment: In that case, using the DropBox API a custom solution should be feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DropBox does have an API with a REST interface - [described here.](http://www.dropbox.com/developers) I think REST may be the way to go compared to BCS.

There's an article showing how it is used (via .NET) - [Create, delete and move folders with the Dropbox REST API.](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/create-delete-and-move-folders)